# Tkinter Cannot Find Image when it is in the same folder

Tags: python, image, tkinter, path, pycharm

I am trying to learn how to add images to tkinter (using a lot of youtube codemy videos).  I have a kingdom management game I have been writing where I have been able to successfully add images as labels and as buttons and have them update as you progress through seasons of time in game.

However, when I started a new py file to work on a separate part of the code, suddenly Pycharm could not find any of the images and I got a:

> "tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "summer.png": no such file or directory".

So, I copied my code that worked in the main instance in a separate py file and it still does not work and I get the same error.  So, for whatever reason, in one file the same code is able to be used and it finds the png but in a second instance (with the "same" code) it cannot.  Also, hovering over the image path allows me to see the image in Pycharm so I know it is still there (the images are in the same folder as my python project). I am wondering if there is something simple I am not seeing. All the below image paths work in my main program but it fails when I attempt to replicate it.

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
import random
from pathlib import Path

root = Tk()
root.title("The Crumbling Kingdom")
root.geometry("1300x800")

bgsummer = PhotoImage(file="summer.png")
worldmap = PhotoImage(file="map1.png")
bgspring = PhotoImage(file="spring.png")
bgwinter = PhotoImage(file="winter.png")
bgfall = PhotoImage(file="fall.png")
worldmap = PhotoImage(file="map1.png")
table = PhotoImage(file="table.png")
side = PhotoImage(file="side.png")
backgroundimage = bgspring
my_background=Label(root, image= backgroundimage)
my_background.place(x=0,y=0, relwidth = 1, relheight =1)
```

Comment: Please add you files and folders tree.

Comment: All files (.py & pngs) are directly in: PycharmProjects>pythonProject1>

Comment: I dont use pycharm, but just guessing, if you could try `file="pythonProject1\\summer.png"`?
Or just the full path to the image: `"C:\\Users\\YOU\\.....\\PyhcarmProjects\\pythonProject1\\summer.png"`?

Comment: Try using the pillow module```bgsummer = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("summer.png"))```